# BitmapFactory decode stream returing null while using inputstream read

Tags: android, bitmap

I have two cases

**First case**

In this case image is showing but the progress dialog is not showing

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int fileSize = connection.getContentLength() / 1000;

stream = connection.getInputStream();
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);


  while((b = stream.read(data))!=-1)
  {
     total += b / 1000;
     publishProgress(String.valueOf(total)+" kb / "+String.valueOf(fileSize)+"kb");
  }


return image;
```

**Log**

```
D/ImageDownload: doInBackground: android.graphics.Bitmap@efb3c21
```

**Second case**
In this case progress dialog is showing but the image is not showing

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int fileSize = connection.getContentLength() / 1000;

stream = connection.getInputStream();

while((b = stream.read(data))!=-1)
{
    total += b / 1000;
    publishProgress(String.valueOf(total)+" kb / "+String.valueOf(fileSize)+"kb");
}

image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+String.valueOf(image));


return image;
```

**Log**

```
D/ImageDownload: doInBackground: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it after 3 hour of struggling

use **ByteArrayOutputStream**

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte []data = new byte[1024];
  int b;
   while((b = stream.read(data))!=-1)
   {
      total += b / 1000;
      publishProgress(String.valueOf(total)+" kb / "+String.valueOf(fileSize)+"kb");
      bos.write(data,0,b);
    }

byte []data = new byte[1024]
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```